# Limit items in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, limit

I am requesting data from a `json` to fill a table. I want to limit to 5 the request.

```
jQuery.getJSON("data/data.json", function(data) {
    var table = $("table");
    $.each(data, function(id, elem) {
        table.append("<tr class='text-center'><td>" + elem.dato1 + "</td><td>" + elem.dato2 + "</td></tr>");
    });
})
```

Or another option is to add boolean key "active" to the data and that it brings me the data items with the value = true. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.slice()` to filter the returned array down to just the first 5 elements.

```
data = data.slice(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `for` loop.

```
var json_arr, limit;
limit = 5; // set limit to whatever you like
json_arr = JSON.parse(json_data);
for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++;) {
  var this_item = json_arr[i];
  table.append(this_item); // do your thing
}
```

Comment: This will access outside the array if the length is < 5.

Answer (score 0):

The best limit you can implement is on your own controller (where you get your data from)

**But** if you don't have access/don't want to change, you can simple achive this by **JavaScript**:

```
var limit = 5; //your Limit
for(var i in data){
    if(i > limit) break;        
    var elem = data[i];
    table.append("<tr class='text-center'><td>" + elem.dato1 + "</td><td>" + elem.dato2 + "</td></tr>");
}
```